# Javascript - Stop function from executing with function

Tags: javascript, function, debugging

I want to insert my `debugger` function inside another JS function and halt the execution.

I know return false/true does the job, but I want my debugger function to do that automatically.

**Example:**

```
<script type="javascript">
    function validateFirstName () {
        //validating first name field
        var fn = $('#firstname').val();
        if(fn == "") {
            $("#errorMsg").html("Please insert first name");
            $("#firstname").focus();
            return false;
        }

        debugger(); //I want to stop everything here

        // if validation passes, redirect browser:
        window.location = 'nextpage.html';
    }

    function debugger () {
        console.log("Some custom message here");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

You'll notice I put my `debugger` function inside the `validateFirstName()` function.

I assumed that `return false` in my `debugger()` function will stop the `validateFirstName()` from executing. But it doesn't.

Without adding return false inside the `validateFirstName()` function, how can I use my **debugger()** function to stop all execution?

Comment: inside your debugger function, throw "reason goes here";

Comment: do you realize that the browser has a `debugger;` statenent which you are now overridding! [MDN Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: You could use the builtin debugger statement epascarello mentioned instead of creating your own debugger function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could throw from `debugger ()` like this.

```
function debugger () {
    console.log('Some custom message here');
    throw 'Debugging Code';
}
```

Although this will do what you want it to, I don't recommend it. Basically what's happening is you are throwing an error which isn't being caught in your code (the browser will catch it, but that is probably not as clean).

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
debugger(); //I want to stop everything here
```

with

```
return debugger(); //I want to stop everything here
```

the above example will always stop on true or false.

This will continue to the window.location if it's true and stop if it's false.

```
if(!debugger())
  return;
```

in your case it seems to be a function inside of a function so you might as well use

```
if(!debugger())
  return false;
```

Seems what you really want to do is set a breakpoint on the executing code.
In Chrome Browser press `Ctrl+Shift+I`
Then Go to `Sources` Tab
Click the Arrow pointing right (looks like a play button) on top of the counting line numbers to see list of websites
Find your website click on the folder
Find whatever script that you want
Now click anywhere in the code to close the side bar
Now finally click on any number on the side thats counting down the lines
That will set a `breakpoint` which means it will stop on that code if you make the code go there by doing something on your website, or forcing the code to run using the
`Console` tab or simply in your address bar typing `javascript: function_to_call();`

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an error:

```
function validateFirstName () {
        //validating first name field
    var fn = $('#firstname').val();
    if(fn==""){
      $("#errorMsg").html("Please insert first name");
          $("#firstname").focus();
      return false;
        }

debugger(); //I want to stop everything here

// if validation passes, redirect browser:
window.location='nextpage.html';

}


function debugger () {
    throw new Error("Some custom message here");
}

try{
    validateFirstName();
}catch(e){
   console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern browser like Chrome, why not just use `debugger` instead?

that will trigger the debugger in your developer tools.

like this:

`debugger; //I want to stop everything here`

notice the missing `()`